# Top speed of my Bajaj Pulsar 135 is decreased after changing Clutch plate

Tags: engine, motorcycle, clutch, bajaj

I would like to know if my clutch plate can be the reason that my top speed is now lower.

Top speed of my bike is 115.  I drove my bike after the clutch plate replacement and the top speed is now 90- 105.

Can My clutch plate replacement cause this issue?

Comment: I don't see how what you are saying is possible.  Changing a clutch doesn't change your gearing.  You probably have a slipping clutch.  Can you edit your question and give a little more attention to adding as much information as you can?  Be sure to add the year of your bike and any additional symptoms.

Comment: When you're at top speed, is your RPM reading the same as before, or lower as well?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way changing a clutch plate is going to limit your top speed. There are two big things which can limit it:

- Engine power
- Transmission/final gearing

I would suggest engine power is down somewhat for some reason, because I doubt your final gearing ratio has had any changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

No and may be, Clutch while plays important role in affecting top speed but as you mentioned you just changed it, should not give less top speed. 
As you got the servicing done there might be few mechanical issues such as

- Slipping clutch (even new ones sometime can be defective thus dissipating power while slipping), caused by worn out disc or incorrect order of discs
- Clutch wire is too tight or too loose.
- faulty clutch master cylinder
- loose clutch master cylinder nut

Some factors that we oversee are not mechanical  such as

- weight between different measurements, weight of petrol/pillion/luggage etc.
- faulty/uneven air pressure in tyres can cause different top speed.
- wind drag, opposing wind can reduce the speed as wind speed can range from 5 Km/h to 15 Km/h in normal days or open fields/highways.

I would suggest following measures -

- multiple speed runs on safe roads while following same acceleration method.
- Keeping petrol amount roughly same while doing speed runs , gist is keeping the weight constant.
- proper air pressure which is neither too bouncy(when you fill higher than suggested) nor too limp ( when air pressure is less than suggested).
- check chain slack.
- check wire slack in both clutch and accelerator cable.
- cleaning of throttle body if due.
- change in air filter if due.